# Error During Compilation of GNU C Library (glibc)

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, glibc

I'm not experienced with system administration, nor the technical details of compiling C-based programs, so bear with me if I say something inaccurate.

Basically, I'm using a computing cluster that has a relatively old OS (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4.3, from ~2006), for which I have no root access. I recurrently run into issues when compiling various programs. One common cause I can see is outdated libraries, notably the C library. I decided to compile a recent version of `glibc`, thinking that linking to this new C library would solve many of my problems (is this sound?). That lead me down a rabbit hole of installing a more recent version of `gcc` and its dependencies (including modern Linux kernel headers).

In any case, I believe I have a working version of `gcc`. Now, when I attempt to compile `glibc` using this new `gcc`, I run into an error during the compilation, as follows (these are the last few lines):

```
[...]
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/login'
make  subdir=elf -C elf ..=../ subdir_lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/elf'
Makefile:896: *** target `.dyn' leaves prerequisite pattern empty.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/elf'
make[1]: *** [elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm at a loss at understanding what

```
Makefile:896: *** target `.dyn' leaves prerequisite pattern empty.  Stop.
```

means and, more importantly, what could possibly solve this. Google and Stack Overflow searches haven't turned anything up.

I'm aware that this is probably due to something relative to my system environment, although I wouldn't know what exactly. If ever I can provide additional information that could help, let me know. I would appreciate a solution, but also a rationale for the solution and perhaps a way of interpreting the error for future reference. Thank you!

**Update**: Installing a more recent version of Make (`make-4.0`) as per @andrewdotn's suggestion did resolve the error, but another one crops up later in the compilation (see below). Any ideas?

```
[...]
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/glibc-2.19/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(ns_print.os): In function `__GI_ns_sprintrrf':
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/ns_print.c:99: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/ns_print.c:728: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/glibc-2.19/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `getanswer':
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:180: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:483: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/glibc-2.19/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `__GI_res_gethostbyname2':
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:510: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/bgrande/software/apollo/glibc-2.19/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os):/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:636: more undefined references to `__stack_chk_guard' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
../Makerules:438: recipe for target '/home/bgrande/software/apollo/glibc-2.19/resolv/libresolv.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/bgrande/software/apollo/glibc-2.19/resolv/libresolv.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19/resolv'
Makefile:213: recipe for target 'resolv/others' failed
make[1]: *** [resolv/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/bgrande/software/apollo/src/glibc-2.19'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: C code shouldn't be affected too much by old toolchain, C++ is another galaxy... What doesn't work with the native toolchain? In any case, compiling new GCC and the whole shebang there will be a huge pain... And changing glibc is something even more intrusive than upgrading to latest RHEL...

Comment: You may be able to install modern Linux kernel headers, but they will do you harm rather than good. The actual kernel you are running must match the headers.

Comment: As for the error you are getting, your Makefile is broken (has invalid syntax) at or around line 896. It is difficult to tell why, or how to fix that, without at least seeing a portion of that Makefile around line 896 (but even then I doubt it, the entire context may be needed).

Comment: Did you try [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/)? It could suite your needs and be easier to build...

Comment: Put the update into a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like it’s caused by an old version of Make. RHEL 4.3 uses Make 3.80 from 2002. Try downloading [Make 3.82 or 4.0 from ftp.gnu.org](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/make/), building it in your home directory, and using that to drive the compile.

Comment: I installed `make-4.0` and that got me passed the point where I used to get the error. Unfortunately, I now have another error later in the process. See my update above.